# How to pass the arguments as list of values delimited by space on command line for a make target?

Tags: command-line, makefile, parameters, command-line-arguments

My Makefile looks as follows:

```
#====================================================
PREFIX_LIST ?= 

append_prefix = $(foreach prefix, $(PREFIX_LIST), myText_$(prefix))

mytarget: 
     echo $(append_prefix)

#====================================================
```

I want PREFIX_LIST to have a list of values delimited by space and pass this as a variable when I build this target from the command line.

Something like (this is not entirely correct):

```
$ make PREFIX_LIST= [list of values] mytarget
```

I already tried passing the values inside the Makefile as:

```
#====================================================
PREFIX_LIST ?= foo bar baz xyz

append_prefix = $(foreach prefix, $(PREFIX_LIST), myText_$(prefix))

mytarget: 
     echo $(append_prefix)

#====================================================
```

and it produced the expected output (see at the bottom)

On the command line:

```
$ make mytarget
```

Output:

```
myText_foo myText_bar myText_baz myText_xyz
```

This is what I also expected. I want to figure out a way to pass the list of values to PREFIX_LIST variable from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose the list in quotes (simple or double):

```
$ make PREFIX_LIST="foo bar baz xyz" mytarget
myText_foo myText_bar myText_baz myText_xyz
```

Note: instead of the `foreach` function you could also use `addprefix`:

```
PREFIX_LIST ?= 

append_prefix = $(addprefix myText_,$(PREFIX_LIST))

mytarget: 
    @echo $(append_prefix)
```

Comment: I think addPrefix is a much better way than iterating over the list and then prepending the prefix. Thanks a lot for the alternate and better solution.

Can you point me to some good resource for Makefile? It will be very helpful.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know a better resource than the [GNU make official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). I is really well written and with many examples. Give it a try, if you are using make frequently, it is worth reading it. Another good resource is Paul's posts (Paul is the GNU make maintainer) on [MadScientist](http://make.mad-scientist.net), just search `make`. There are many gems there for advanced users as for beginners.